Moving conda environments cross-platform offline
I am currently working with Anaconda on windows. I want to move the virtual environment to my other system, which uses linux as operating system. The problem is that the linux system doesn't have access to the internet, so I need to somehow download all the standalone installation files from windows system and move them to linux system. How do I cope with this?
It is a supplementary problem, but I'm also having a hard time 'cause I don't know how to manage the virtual environments in conda to have duplicate packages with different versions. I will be very thankful to get a solution on my problems
Packing and unpacking environment directory does not work due to different platform, and exporting via yml file also doesn't work due to internet problem.

How about using WSL to install a linux conda, then install the env, pack and unpack it to your offline machine

how to manage the virtual environments in conda to have duplicate packages with different versions - a single environment cannot have the same package twice

@FlyingTeller What I meant was installing different versions of a same package in different virtual environments.

I see, that should work without second thougt. just do conda activate EnvA; conda install <package=X.X> and conda activate EnvB; conda install <package=Y.Y>

Is there anything different when I use pip? pip kinda seems like just installing everything on the base venv.

@user25075037 pip installs packages into that environment from which its python runs. To install packages into an environment you need to activate that environment and install Python and pip into that environment (conda install pip works); then use pip to install packages.

Two ideas for your cross-platform issue:
A)
Use WSL on your windows machine, download and install miniconda there, solve for the environment that you want, then use conda pack to pack and ship it to your offline machine
B)
Create a dummy env on windows, set the subdir to linux and then use --download-only to populate the pkgs directory with the required packages, then move those files to your linux machine and use conda install --offline:
conda create -n linux_64
conda activate linux_64
conda config --env --set subdir linux-64
conda install --download-only python numpy pandas matplotlib #whatever packages you want

You will get Invalid archive errors, which stem from the fact that linux packages often contain simlinks which cannot be unpacked on windows. In your pkgs directory, you should have a bunch of .conda files now, which you should copy to your offline machines pkgs dir and then run
conda install --offline python numpy pandas matplotlib #whatever packages you want
